# My pom.xml contains this maven-formatter-plugin, but does not build. Do I need to define the format goal?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, pom.xml

Error:

```
Failed to execute goal net.revelc.code.formatter:formatter-maven-plugin:2.8.1:format (default) on project processing-parent:
The parameters 'encoding' for goal net.revelc.code.formatter:formatter-maven-plugin:2.8.1:format are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

pom.xml file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.revelc.code.formatter</groupId>
            <artifactId>formatter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>format</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    ... //more plugins
    </plugins>
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.revelc.code.formatter</groupId>
            <artifactId>formatter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <configFile>${project.basedir}/formatter.xml</configFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ... //more plugins
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

I followed the documentation for the plugin and I am running into this issue. I also compared this to a colleague, but it seems that his works and mine does not. I also tried moving the config to the other declaration with the goal with the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is inside the `formatter.xml` file, most probably.
Check the first line, which should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

Look for the `encoding` attribute.

If that is not the case, you can specify an encoding value inside the configuration block

```
<configuration>
    <configFile>${project.basedir}/formatter.xml</configFile>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I seem to have that as well. But I did add this under properties in the pom.xml which worked.

`<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>`

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: By the way I have that first line and I still needed to add the config

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>`

Comment: still not working for me
suddenly started raising this error